# getting error expression expected in asp.net, when trying to check radiobutton using db value

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, radio-button, repeater

There are 4 readiobutton inside the repeater and i'm trying to show the checked radiobutton from database value.

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="rb_option1" GroupName="answer" CssClass="frm_label"
    Checked='<%# IIF(Eval("ANSWER")==1,true,false) %>'
     Text='<%# Eval("OPTION1")%>' runat="server" />
```

Second approach

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="rb_option1" GroupName="answer" CssClass="frm_label"
Checked='<%# Eval("ANSWER")==1 ? true : false %>'
 Text='<%# Eval("OPTION1")%>' runat="server" />
```

and so on for the rest radiobutton. But, it showing the error `Expression Expected` error. Need help. !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've got your C# and VB.Net mixed. Your first example looks like VB, the second like C#. However, you've got a few problems in your VB implementation:

- The equality operator in VB is `=`, not `==`
- You should use the `IF` operator, not the `IIF` function, which is obsolete

The correct code should be as follows:

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="rb_option1" GroupName="answer" CssClass="frm_label"
  Checked='<%# IF(Eval("ANSWER")=1,true,false) %>'
  Text='<%# Eval("OPTION1")%>' runat="server" />
```

Comment: getting error `Operator '=' is not defined for type 'DBNull' and type 'Integer'.` What should i do ?

Comment: Check for DBNull: `<%# IF((Eval("ANSWER") <> DBNull.Value) AndAlso (Eval("ANSWER")=1),true,false) %>`

Comment: @Jonas It works fine, but facing one problem, since i have used radiobutton inside repeater. So, once i select one radio-button and update it on table, then for the next page the same radio-button is already selected. How can i solve this problem